# How to use global XYZ coordinates for displacement?

Tags: modifiers, coordinates

I like to use *Global* texture coordinates combined with the *RGB to XYZ* direction setting on a displacement modifier to displace multiple separate objects uniformly.  I.e. if two separate objects with the same displacement texture are placed next to each other, the displacement contour will flow smoothly from one to the next (see GIF below).

However, even when the *texture coordinates* are set to Global, the XYZ displacement *direction* is local.  So if I rotate one of the objects about the Y-axis (as seen below) the local Z-up displacement vector is now global Z-down, and thus the displacement contour is broken between objects.

[image]

*Both objects are just stretched and subdivided cubes.*

So is there a way to use global space for XYZ displacement instead of local space, either directly or by some hack/workaround?

Comment: Are they independent objects or do are they linked duplicates?

Comment: @cegaton  They are completely independent objects.

Comment: havr you tried having an empty to control the displacement?

Comment: @cegaton  That does the same thing as global coordinates except it allows you to move the origin point of the texture.  My problem is that the coordinates used for the displacement itself (not the mapping coordinates) are local.

Comment: I think that the displacement is global but not in all directions. That does not help directly.. I know... but intuitively, having it in all directions needs UV in the texture coordinates... so not a global...

Comment: This seems to be close to the "brick texture problem", am I wrong ? I mean Z axis is the displacement axis (if no UV selected in the texture coordinates) ?

Comment: For now I "conclude" that what we need here is "generated" in the texture coordinates... but not available

Comment: @lemon  I'm not sure what you mean.  The texture coordinates are fine, it's the coordinate system used for the actual displacement that I need to be global.

Comment: yes but if you set them global (at least in my tests for that) you will not obtain the displacement in all directions. Am I wrong ?

Comment: @lemon  What do you mean?  My problem is that there is no way to set them to global.  When you select global on the displacement modifier that is for the mapping coordinates of the displacement texture (which I do need to global as well), not the coordinate system used to displace the geometry.

Answer (score 1):

The vector displacement space for RGBtoXYZ mode is always local, unfortunately. (tangent would be useful in a lot of cases too). The good news if you need global space though, is you can apply your rotation (object > apply > rotation from the 3d view header) and bake your rotation into the mesh. This gets rid of the object level rotation meaning local space = global space once again.

Comment: The issue with applying rotation for my current project is that it would mess up the other modifiers on the objects.  I am working on a set of modular pipes that I can quickly duplicate and place and I would like to not have to make multiple different objects for the different orientations of each type of pipe.